# SipManager doesn't be registered to SipRegistrationListener

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, sip

Firstly, I used this code and my app crashed:

```
mysipregistrationlistener:=TJSipRegistrationListener.create;
```

Next code is running for me:

```
mysipmanager.setRegistrationListener(mysipprofile.getUriString,mySipRegistrationListener);
mysipmanager.open(mysipprofile,mypendingintent,mySipRegistrationListener);
```

Next step: I used this code for registration:

```
mysipmanager.register(mysipprofile,30,mySipRegistrationListener);
```

But I got this error:

**android.net.sip.SipException:
SipService.createSession() returns null.**

How can I do registered my SipManager to my SipRegistrationListener?

Thanks,

Best Regards.

Editted: My new Unit, But some things missing for me.

```
unit Androidapi.JNI.SIPREG;

interface

uses

  Androidapi.JNIBridge,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.JNI.Net;

type

  TMySipRegistrationListener = class(TJavaLocal, JSipRegistrationListener)
  private
  public
    constructor Create;
    procedure onRegistering(localProfileUri: JString); cdecl;
    procedure onRegistrationDone(localProfileUri: JString; expiryTime: integer); cdecl;
    procedure onRegistrationFailed(localProfileUri: JString; errorCode: integer; errorMessage: JString); cdecl;
  end;

implementation

constructor TMySipRegistrationListener.Create;
begin
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMySipRegistrationListener.onRegistering(localProfileUri: JString);
begin
//
end;

procedure TMySipRegistrationListener.onRegistrationDone(localProfileUri: JString; expiryTime: Integer);
begin
//
end;

procedure TMySipRegistrationListener.onRegistrationFailed(localProfileUri: JString; errorCode: Integer; errorMessage: JString);
begin
//
end;

end.
```

Comment: SipRegistrationListener is an interface, not a class. You need to construct a class that implements it, similar to how I implement JViewTreeObserver_OnGlobalLayoutListener  here: https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/KastriFree/blob/master/Core/DW.VirtualKeyboardRect.Android.pas

Comment: Hello, Dear Dave, Very Thanks for your precious comment. I will try this for my SipRegistrationListener. Best Regards.

Comment: Dear Dave, My new Unit, But some things missing for me.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the listener is merely to provide feedback to the user, as per this Java example: http://www.javased.com/?api=android.net.sip.SipRegistrationListener. In theory, you could (at least initially) leave those empty

Comment: Dear Dave, OK. Firstly, I will try without SipRegistrationListener for to create SipSession and to make call. I hope Finally, I will do Sip Audio Call app on Delphi. :) Thanks for everyhing. Best Regards.